# How to add custom condition to Sonata global search feature

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I would like to add a custom condition to the queries which are generated by Sonata Search feature. The problem is that i have 'status' column which should be set as "active". On the List View i do not have any problem because I am able to set:

```
protected $datagridValues = array (
    'status' => array ('type' => 1, 'value' => Status::ACTIVE)
);
```

and then all queries check if the status field is set properly.
But the problem is with global search. I can override SearchHandler and force desired behavior, but i can't change any files from vendor/ directory, so i have two questions.

1. How can i inject my own SearchHandler, which configuration file i need to change and how
2. Maybe there is a simpler way to develope needed solution?

Comment: Post your solution as your own answer and accept it after the acceptance period,So that future visitors can see this question as solved and if it is really helpful then you will get upvotes for your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:

I have figure out how can i inject my own SearchHandler. The following code is used for that:
1.  Just edit your services.yml file and put something like that:

```
    cmsbundle.search.handler:
        class: XXX\CmsBundle\Search\SearchHandler
        arguments:
        -  @sonata.admin.pool
    sonata.admin.block.search_result:
        class: XXX\CmsBundle\Search\AdminSearchBlockService
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.block }
        arguments:
            - sonata.admin.block.search_result
            - @templating
            - @sonata.admin.pool
            - @cmsbundle.search.handler
```

2. Create the file "XXX\CmsBundle\Search\AdminSearchBlockService" and change SearchHandler instance to yours own
3. Create the file "XXX\CmsBundle\Search\SearchHandler" and change implementation. It can be something like that:

   ```
   foreach ($datagrid->getFilters() as $name => $filter) {
       /** @var $filter FilterInterface */
       if ($filter->getOption('global_search', false)) {
           if ($filter->getName() !== 'status') {
               $filter->setCondition(FilterInterface::CONDITION_OR);
               $datagrid->setValue($name, null, $term);
           } else {
               $filter->setCondition(FilterInterface::CONDITION_AND);
               $datagrid->setValue($name, null, 'active');
           }
           $found = true;
       }
   }
   ```

**IMPORTANT**

'status' field must be added to configureDatagridFilters method in Admin class.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd add my solution to this problem.

My problem was similar, my Admin class would modify the Admin Entities' respective createQuery. This query would add in restrictions so that the user can only view their models, or only view things which are not deleted for example.

The problem is the `SearchHandler.php` would set ALL filters as

`$filter->setCondition(FilterInterface::CONDITION_OR);`

This would cause queries to look like:

```
( myAddedCondition OR filterCondition OR filterCondition OR filterCondition )
```

What I really wanted instead was:

```
( myAddedCondition )  AND ( filterCondition OR filterCondition OR filterCondition )
```

In order to achieve this, I registered a GLOBAL ASTWalker which iomplements the `walkWhereClause` method.. Then in the Walker I would manually edit the generated SQL to suit my requirements.